# Installing ubuntu to my windows 8 tablet pc

Tags: installation, windows, windows-8, secure-boot

I bought a samsung tablet pc and there comes windows 8 at the beginning of my tablet pc I want to install latest ubuntu version and delete windows totally but when i am trying to install ubuntu while i am rebooting my pc its giving me a error. please help me. I love ubuntu and i want to use it so much

Comment: What error do you get? Please add the error message or a screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disableing Secure boot. On windows 8: Hold the shift key and then click restart from the power menu then you should reboot into the settings screen Do you see a UEFI option? if you don't click on the advanced options tile.